# How to get if item exist in IEnumerable using Linq

Tags: c#

How would you refactor this method?

```
    private bool IsTermExist(string word)
    {
        var query = from term in m_xdoc.Descendants("Term")
                    where term.Attribute("Name").Value.ToUpper().Contains(word.ToUpper())
                    select term;

        return query.Any();
    }
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve by re-factoring it?

Answer (score 6):

I would probably use the overload of `Any` which accepts a predicate:

```
private bool TermExists(string word)
{
    return m_xdoc.Descendants("Term")
       .Any(term => term.Attribute("Name").Value
                        .IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Notes:

- Using `ToUpper` for case-insensitivity is generally fraught (e.g. due to behaviour in Turkish which is unexpected to most developers); using the [overload of `IndexOf` which takes a `StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx) is preferred. (There's a similar overload for `Equals`.)
- If we *were* going to compare with `word.ToUpper()`, we could extract it so that `word.ToUpper()` is only executed once, instead of once per `Term` element. (Micro-optimization aside, I think it's generally a nice idea to extract the iteration-invariant parts of a query first. But don't expect consistency on this front :)
- This code will still go bang for `Term` elements without `Name` attributes. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: The easiest way to do case-insensitive `string.Contains` the Right Way in .NET is to use `IndexOf` -- see my answer.

Comment: I just saw them so I deleted my question :o)

Comment: @mquander: Thanks, fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the first matching item instead how about a method that either returns an item or `null` if not found:

```
private XElement? GetTerm(string word)
{
      var query = from term in m_xdoc.Descendants("Term")
                  where term.Attribute("Name").Value.ToUpper().Contains(word.ToUpper())
                  select term;

      return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write this:

```
private static bool MatchesName(XElement el, string name)
{
    var attr = el.Attribute("Name");
    return attr.Value.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}

private bool TermExists(string word)
{
    return m_xdoc.Descendants("Term").Any(e => MatchesName(e, word));
}
```

Hard to say where to split off the helper method without seeing other code, though.